# Explanation regarding modulo operator and Math.floor function

Tags: javascript, function, modulo

I have two functions:

```
function getDigitsSum(number) {
  var sum = 0;

  while (number > 0) {

    sum += number % 10;
    number = Math.floor(number / 10);
  }

  return sum; 
}


function findNumbers() {

   var results = [];

   for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      if (getDigitsSum(i) == 8) {
        results.push(i);
      }
   }

   return results;
}
```

Essentially I am displaying numbers from 1 to 100 whose sum of digits equal 8. I understand the second function completely but not the first function.

This I don't understand:

```
while (number > 0) {

    sum += number % 10;
    number = Math.floor(number / 10);
  }
```

My questions would be:

1. What is the role of the modulo operator in this part of the code? I always thought it simply returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. Here it seems to have a different purpose of which I wasn't aware of. Why does it do what it does and how?
2. I understand what the `Math.floor` function is supposed to do but not what `(number / 10)` means while concerning the rest of the code. Why exactly is `number` divided by 10?

If there is an alternative code to this one, which of course gives the same result, I would be glad to see it.

Comment: `% 10` basically means : get the last digit of the number. 2) `1234` -> `123` -> `12` -> `1`

Comment: `number % 10` returns the rightmost digit of `number`.  `number / 10` returns the number with the rightmost digit removed.

Comment: Another way to think about it - how would *you* go about calculating the digit sum of a number?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth First I would have to identify the number by how many digits it has, then define the value of each digit, then sum them up. By the looks of it, here we go from the last, rightmost digit, and then go steadily to the beginning. It makes sense, I just wasn't sure how certain aspects of it work or why it was done that way. It just seems a bit more roundabout than direct.

Answer (score 0):

Like the function's name tells, it builds the sum over all digits of a number. I.e. `getDigitsSum(12345) => 15`.

To your first question:
The modulo operator (in this case) does what you thought it does. It divides `number` by 10, leaving the rest as return value. Hence, `11 % 10` would be 1, `12 % 10` would be 2 and `5 % 3` is also 2.

So `number % 10` gives you the 'rightmost' digit of a number: `12345 => 5`

Your second question:
`number` is divided by 10 to cut off the rightmost digit. This is done, so the next iteration in the loop will operate on `1234` instead of `12345`.

**edit**:
Concerning your last question about alternatives. There's plenty of them. Depending on your input, you could operate on the String rather than the Number:

```
function getDigitsSum(number) {
    return ('' + number).split('').reduce(function(sum, digit) {
        return sum + Number(digit);
    }, 0)
}
```

Wether this is any clearer or more efficient is open to debate, though.

Comment: Of course, you're right. Was maybe a bit too figurative.

Answer (score 0):

`x % y` (x modulo y) means, that you do an integer division `x/y` and substract the rest from x.

e.g. `17%5 = 2` because `int(17/5) = 3`, `5*3 = 15`, `17-15 = 2`.

The idea of

```
while (number > 0) {
    sum += number % 10;
    number = Math.floor(number / 10);
}
```

is, that in each step you get the remainder of `number / 10`, which is the numbers last digit, and then remove that digit for the next step, by doing an integer division on the number using `Math.floor(number / 10);`. You keep doing that, until the number is 0, and then stop for obvious reasons.

Comment: How would that go for let's say the number 17 in your example?

Comment: As explained, `17%10` would be `7`, as just `1*10` fits into 17, and `17 - 1*10 = 7`. Having the 7, it would divide the number by 10 and floor that -> `Math.floor( 17 / 10 ) = Math.floor( 1.7) = 1`, therefore `number` would be 1 in the next iteration, `1 % 10`is just 1, as 10 doesn't fit in there, and both the 7 and the 1 are added to sum by `sum += ...`, `sum` would now be 8. `Math.floor( 1/10 )` would return `0`, hence `number = 0` and the loop ends.

Comment: Thank you foe the clarification. One more question. It would have been different if the divisor wasn't 10. Is it a rule to use 10 in this situation?

Comment: In this very situation, in which case you want to know the last digit of a number, you have to use 10. The last digit is just the remainder, that's left if you divide the number by 10. `12345%10 = 5`, because `12340` would be the next lower number that can be divided by `10`, so the rest is `5`. Is that what you meant?